# Show MessageBox on Datagridview Checkbox before Check or UnCheck

Tags: vb.net, winforms, checkbox, datagridview, datagridviewcheckboxcell

How to show a msgbox before update the checkbox in datagridview?

Lets say I have a row with checkbox in Datagridview and the value of it is True(Checked) and I will click it. How can I show something like this first?

"Are you sure you want to uncheck this? Yes or No"

Yes = Uncheck

No = Still the same (Checked)

here is my code with the output i want but its not working

```
 Private Sub DataGridView3SelectAll_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(
      ByVal sender As Object,
      ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView3.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged

        RemoveHandler DataGridView3.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged,
            AddressOf DataGridView3SelectAll_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged

        If TypeOf DataGridView3.CurrentCell Is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell Then
            DataGridView3.EndEdit()
            Dim Checked As Boolean = CType(DataGridView3.CurrentCell.Value, Boolean)
            Dim xx As String
            xx = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to save changes?", vbYesNo)
            If xx = vbYesNo Then
                If Checked = True Then
                    Dim s As String = (DataGridView3.Columns(DataGridView3.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex).DataPropertyName)
                    Dim x As Integer
                    x = DataGridView3.CurrentCell.RowIndex
                    Dim con1 As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("datasource=192.168.2.87;database=inventory;userid=root;password=admin1950")
                    Dim cmdinsert As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("update stock_issuance set `" & s & "` = 1 where `" & s & "` = `" & s & "` and Month = '" & DataGridView3.Rows(x).Cells(1).Value & "'", con1)
                    con1.Open()
                    cmdinsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    con1.Close()
                ElseIf Checked = False Then
                    Dim s As String = (DataGridView3.Columns(DataGridView3.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex).DataPropertyName)
                    Dim x As Integer
                    x = DataGridView3.CurrentCell.RowIndex
                    Dim con1 As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("datasource=192.168.2.87;database=inventory;userid=root;password=admin1950")
                    Dim cmdinsert As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("update stock_issuance set `" & s & "` = 0 where `" & s & "` = `" & s & "` and Month = '" & DataGridView3.Rows(x).Cells(1).Value & "'", con1)
                    con1.Open()
                    cmdinsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    con1.Close()
                End If
            Else

            End If
        End If


        AddHandler DataGridView3.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged,
            AddressOf DataGridView3SelectAll_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first set [`ReadOnly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.readonly(v=vs.110).aspx) property of column to `True`, then handle [`CellContentClick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentclick(v=vs.110).aspx) event of `DataGridView` this way:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    If (e.ColumnIndex = 0 AndAlso e.RowIndex >= 0) Then
        Dim result = MessageBox.Show("Check Item?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel)
        If (result = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes) Then
            DataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value = True
        Else
            DataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

To make the column `ReadOnly` you can use both [code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cze614bb(v=vs.110).aspx) and [designer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/xd4k3c7e(v=vs.110)).

---

To get confirm only when unchecking the cell:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    If (e.ColumnIndex = 0 AndAlso e.RowIndex >= 0) Then
        Dim value = DirectCast(DataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).FormattedValue, _
                               Nullable(Of Boolean))
        If (value.HasValue AndAlso value = True) Then
            Dim result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to uncheck item?", "", _
                                          MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel)
            If (result = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes) Then
                DataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value = False
            End If
        Else
            DataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any question about this answer.

Comment: all I can say is you are my master TYSSSSSMMM +1 and approve

Comment: Sir are you still there?

Comment: Sir to make it more simple can we do something like this? A msgbox will show saying "Are you sure you want to save the changes?" If yes then check the current value. If the value is yes then make it no and save the value in database and if No make it yes and also save to database. And if I will click NO in the messagebox the selected value stays the same. I hope I make it clearer sir. :)

Comment: I believe the post currently is clear and you can simply apply any other criteria on the solution :)

Comment: is it ok with you sir If i update my post so u can check my current code?

Comment: It's better to ask another question about it if you think it's needed. But I believe you have enough  data to solve the problem. `Dim value = DirectCast(DataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).FormattedValue,  Nullable(Of Boolean))` will tell you the value of cell. Also you can set the value of cell by assigning any value to `DataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value` so you have anything you need.

Comment: Noted on this sir I think I have enough, I will fix condition statement. TYSSSSS much for a great help

Answer (score 0):

Handle the `CellValidating` event. Then, if it's your column, popup a `msgbox`. If they wish to abort the change then set `e.Cancel=true`

```
Private Sub dgv_CellValidating(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles dgv.CellValidating
    If dgv.Columns(e.ColumnIndex) Is myCheckboxColumn Then
        If DialogResult.Yes <> MessageBox.Show("Are you sure", "?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) Then
            e.Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```